# Code analyzer which warn dev to use async methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to improve my legacy code by using analyzers but what I cant find is a rule to "force" async usage.

So calling ToList() instead of its async equivalent ToListAsync() it should be a warning.

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source,
      Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)

 public static Task<TSource> FirstOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(
      [NotNull] this IQueryable<TSource> source,
      [NotNull] Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
```

So in case of firstOrDefault if Async extension exist it should warn dev to use it.

PS1. Thank you guys for all your minuses without understanding my question and even asking.

PS2. Option 1. https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD103.md

Comment: How would the compiler know that the method should be async?

Comment: @John Maybe i was unclear. Let me update question.

Comment: @John I've updated question

Comment: @John its not about making method async its about calling async methods instead of blocking

Comment: So if there's a method (by convention) whose name is the same but ends with `Async`, you want a rule that will tell the developer to use that? And yes, I did understand your question as it was worded - and wondered about cases where the developer didn't suffix their method name with "Async", even though it's an async method, or (an alternative interpretation) why you wanted to force all methods to be async. In short: I didn't find your question to be clear enough. It is now :)

Comment: @John you are absolutely correct

Comment: @John I already found rules for naming convention how to Force naming Async for methods which returns Task. Now is more about to find blocking calls usage. Its specially important for calls to database, elasticsearch and some other cloud services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a Roslyn Analyzer, I use the Async Converter plugin for ReSharper (paid Visual Studio Extension) that seems to fit your analyser requirements. It'll refactor synchronous methods to their async counterparts by convention, picking a method overload with a CancellationToken, if one exists.

Gallery Link: https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/AsyncConverter.AsyncConverter/